# Any suggestion on how to justify true/false question in linear algebra exams?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I have hard time bringing words on paper when it comes to *true false* justification of linear algebra problems.

My technique is to use counter example for *false* and use book theorems for *true* ones.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it depends on the questions. What kind of exam are you supposed to take? Multiple choices?

Comment: I use this type of questions in my exams frequently. Your approach is the one I recommended  to my students (I might say that  I demand such an approch from them). You may need to build a logical chain of a few links to justify "true", but the individual links are often theorems proven during the course.

Comment: Some concrete examples would help us identify the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the question itself.

**Example 1: True claim**

> If $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and $\dim(W)=\dim(V)$ then $W=V$

In this type of T/F question which is true you will use what you called
book theorems to prove it.

**Example 2: True claim**

> There exist $n>0$ s.t  $$ \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1
>  & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
>  \end{bmatrix}^{n}=0 $$
>
> where $0$ is stands for the $5\times5$ matrix.

In this case the claim is true, but to prove it we won't use book
theorems (probably) but we can calculate that for $n=5$ the equality
holds and this will suffice to prove the existence of such $n$

And similarly for false claims - for example if in the first example
we were asked if $W\neq V$ then we could just give a counter example,
and if we were asked if there exist $n$ such that $I^{n}=0$ then
the claim is false but we would have to disprove it and we could not
do so with counter examples - we would really have to prove that that
there does not exist such an $n$

To make things a little bit more clear:

If a claim is "something will always happen'' - if its true then
prove it and if it false give a counterexample

If a claim is "There exist .. such that something happens'' - if
its true it suffice to find such a case where it happens and if it
false we need to prove that it never happens.

If you have trouble with other types of questions feel free to comment

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is easier in forward path (meaning from premises generate an answer), then follow forward path.

Else if reverse path is easier (meaning from results get to premises) follow that path (as mentioned in comments below, using equivalences and not simple implications to be correct).

Else (try to) find (simple) counter-examples. It is surprising how easy is to find simple counter-examples, in some cases, and effectively prove sth as false (if the positive is given in question).

In any case verify the final result/counter-example you get to be sure. These are just speed hacks for solving (multiple-choice) exam questions

Another set of tips and tricks for speed answering, having to do with actual calculations (and not just inference or equivalences), involves having  a "library" of results and simplifications already prepared (in your memory for example) and use them to derive results fast (without having to re-invent every intermediate little theorem or relation) and so on.

Comment: I think you are wrong about reverse path. Can anyone comment regarding using the "reverse path" usage of theorems?

Comment: @EhsanSadeghmoghaddam, well the general idea, is given a relationship and then extract or prove sth else, sometimes it is easier (at least conceptually) to start from the result and do a reverse process (as long as using equivalences and not simple implications) can do the trick

Comment: So are you saying for example I could say if a matrix is one to one and onto then by big therom it must be n x n?

Comment: @EhsanSadeghmoghaddam, yes sth like this, i think in this example you mean matrix has full rank

Comment: Well I said that on a quiz and prof gave me zero points. After, an hour of argue, I understood that he thinks that the theorem "implies" therefore its one direction usage is accepted (not reverse). In another word, X =A,B but cannot say A,B = X. So, it's more like x => A,B.

Comment: @EhsanSadeghmoghaddam, that's exactly why it was mentioned to use equivalences (as long they actually hold of course) when doing a calculation in reverse direction

Comment: where was it mentioned?

Comment: @EhsanSadeghmoghaddam, another trick which can be useful sometimes, is trying to derive counter-examples, when the question actually is true, the very process of trying to find counter-exampls can also lead to a positive proof (many examples of this effect in literature, used as starting intuition)

Comment: @EhsanSadeghmoghaddam, it was mentioned in my 1st comment which replied to your 1st comment about exacly this issue (which i assumed as already known)

Comment: Oh OK. I miss understood that... so is all theorems are not equivalences? or how do I know if it is an equivalency?

Comment: @EhsanSadeghmoghaddam, no all theorems do not hold in both directions in general (only those that say "if and only if" do that). Using equivalences means that a mathematical step can go in either direction without introducing extra premises or conditions, if this not so, then equivalence does not hold and only an implication holds. Example: $a < b$ and $b < c$ implies $a < c$, **but** having only $a < c$ and $b < c$ does **not imply** $a < b$

Comment: ok thx for clarification